# Can a simple PC (windows 10) having TwinCAT XAR be used as a target in host computer having TwinCAT 3 XAE

Tags: remote-desktop, twincat, twincat-ads-.net

I want to know if I can use a system(run time pc) with Windows 10 OS which has TwinCAT XAR installed in it as a remote system. In other words can I select it as a target? Do we need any extra settings to make it work or it will work just like any other hardware controller?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can select a Windows 10 PC with TwinCAT XAR installed as a remote target, however the performance may not be the same as you would get with purchasing a known hardware configuration from Beckhoff.

As noted in the [Beckhoff documentation](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_installation/179470219.html&id=):

> For a reliable, optimized and performant realtime behavior, a
> completely aligned system design (hardware, BIOS, OS, drivers,
> realtime-runtime) is mandatory. Each single component of the control
> system has to be checked and optimized for this type of application -
> that is the one and only way for an optimal, reliable and performant
> realtime behavior. Beckhoff IPCs are optimized in each detail for this
> type of operation. There is no guarantee for proper, reliable realtime
> behavior on third-party PCs.

To use any Windows PC as a remote target, you need to ensure that the XAR is installed and that the Windows firewall is open to ADS. See also [routing through a firewall](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcremoteaccess/html/tcremoteaccess_firewall.html&id=). Specifically, you should open port 48898 to incoming TCP traffic and port 48899 to incoming UDP traffic in the Windows firewall. After this, you should be able to create a route normally using the IP address of the target PC through the ADS router on your development system.

You may also want to isolate a CPU core on the target system and dedicate TwinCAT tasks to it to ensure more consistent realtime behavior.

Finally, you need to purchase a license for the PLC if you intend to use it for a purpose other than development. This requires the higher performance level >= P90 and a license dongle, see [this note about TwinCAT 3 licenses for non-Beckhoff IPCs](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_licensing/179888523.html&id=1816461201887989327).

Comment: I am using another windows-PC as a Runtime PC. I followed the select Target method. The target system is available by Broadcast search. But, I am unable to connect to it because remote user credentials are unavailable. I have tried the system password and also the default value "1". Can you you guide me on How can I get the password for the Remote User Credentials in TwinCAT 3 XAE. I have already done the TCP and UDP settings in the runtime PC.